# How to compare jQuery val() and JavaScript value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, html-input

When I do the following comparison I get false although both val() and value visually display the same value:12

```
if ($(this).val() == txt.value)//returns false
```

When I alert both $(this).val() and txt.value I get 12. Is one of them a string and the other one an int? If so, which one's what?

Comment: What kind of node does this refer to, and how are you defining txt?

Comment: I have a select and a input text element. I compare the txt.value to each of the option values in the select. I get option value with $(this).val() and the value of the text box with txt.value. Note that this is performed inside $.each.

Comment: can you run a simple demo on JSFiddle?

Comment: I tried to make a demo but I can't add anything to html pane in JSFiddle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do a `typeof` to know the types of your values.

```
console.log(typeof $(this).val());
console.log(typeof txt.value);
```

---

jQuery could have altered the values when using `.val()` like trim whitespaces that should be present. To make sure, you can avoid using `val()`.

The `this` in `.each()` as well as the second argument is the DOM element per iteration. You could [get the value of the `option` directly](http://jsfiddle.net/fTLCX/1/):

```
$('select > option').each(function(i,el){
   //we should be getting small caps values
   console.log(this.value);
   console.log(el.value);
});
```

---

When using loose comparison (`==`), number 12 and string 12 should be the same. Even more surprising is that it's true even with the string having whitespaces around it. But with strict comparison (`===`), they shouldn't be:

```
"12"    ==  12  // true
" 12  " ==  12  // true; tested on Firefox 20 (nightly)
"12"    === 12  // false
```

---

At this point, we have weeded all thinkable gotchas. If none worked, both could be totally different values in the first place.

Comment: " 12" == 12 // true; tested on Chrome 23

Comment: Sorry guys, I've realized that the issue was not that the values did not match but because I was trying to return from the function if the condition was true. The condition is indeed true, but somehow the code continues after leaving the $.each loop.

Comment: jQuery will not trim whitespace when calling `.val()`, but will replace `/\r/g` with `''`, or return a null value as `''`

Answer (score 0):

I feel obliged to write so comments, which I find very useful, after taking so much time of the guys around here. So my problem was this:

```
('#mySelect option').each(function({
  if ($(this).val() == txt.value)
    return;
});
alert('Code still continues');
```

Although the result of the condition $(this).val() == txt.value was true the code after the each loop still executed. That's why I thought that the two values did not match. But if
I put an alert inside this condition it showed up. It means something wrong was with the behavior of "return" inside the each loop. I've lately come to understand that although return stops the execution of the code after itself inside the each loop, it does not prevent the code from executing after the each block. Thus, to achieve the full function return inside the jquery each loop we seem to have to put a flag and decide if to return after the each according to this flag. The following code worked for me:

```
var shouldContinue = true;
('#mySelect option').each(function ()
{
    if ($(this).val() == txt.value) {
        shouldContinue = false;
        return (false);
    }
});
if (!shouldContinue)
    return;
```

Note return(false) inside the iteration. What this means is, if the condition is true continue iterating no more and leave the loop.